# How do I simulate a key press of “fn + shift + command + L” on a Mac?

Tags: c, macos, applescript

I need it to be the equivalent of physically pressing those keys simultaneously.

I actually think it’s not possible in AppleScript, I’ve scoured the Internet to no avail, but then again I’m a noob, so maybe I missed something.

If it is impossible in AppleScript, how can I do this on a lower level. Maybe in C?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by pressing those keys? I'm not aware of any command mapped to that key combination.

Comment: @duskwuff: shift-command-L seems to be used in a number of different contexts, but I don't even think it's possible to assign the function key to typical keyboard shortcuts. I'd like an explanation as well. Frankly, I find this whole request a little off-putting.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley I’m using this program figma, and it has a keyboard shortcut of command+shift+L that is supposed to work for locking an element, but for some reason it doesnt work, but does work if I also press the fn key. Now I thought it would be a really simple task to remap command+L using keyboard maestro to make it so when I press command+L, it then executes an apple script that eumulates fn+command+shift+L, I’ve been at it for 4 hours and I thought it would be simple, but it isn’t apparently.

Comment: @DonjiYD command-shift-L *is* super easy to emulate; it's that odd fn thing that's creating headaches. There are only three reasons I can think that might happen (1) you have a setting weird in System Preferences->keyboard or System Preferences->Accessibility. (2) you have water-damage on your keyboard which is shorting out the fn key. (3) the figma app you're using is messed up, and you should contact the developer. check those possibilities out while I think about the problem; mapping the fn key is not easy.

Answer (score 5):

you can do it using appleScript, here is a working code for you. 
It does exactly what you need.

It will press those keys sequentially while keep holding: **Fn** key, **Shift** key, **Command** key and **L** key.

It will wait 2 seconds keeping them pressed (I just inserted the delay to test it while observing it on the MacOS Screen Keyboard pressing those keys). For production I suggest reducing the **delay to 0.2**

After the delay it releases all the keys.

This is exactly like physically pressing the keys.

```
tell application "System Events"
    -- part 1: press and keep holding
    key down 63
    key down shift
    key down command
    key down "L"
    -- part 2: lets keep them pressed for 2 seconds
    delay 2
    -- part 3: release the keys
    key up "L"
    key up command
    key up shift
    key up 63
end tell
```

Code 63 is the keycode for Fn Key.

**And you can remap this script to your Command+L shortcut in Maestro as you asked/need**

For security reasons Apple prohibits by default any automation control by any application, so you will have to authorise this script as trustable to control your computer.

To authorise it:

- Open System Preferences -> Security and Privacy
- Go to tab: Privacy
- On the items on the listing on the left select: Accessibility
- unlock the dialog to make changes
- click + button and
- add your script to the list of apps allowed to control your computer.

(To test it using Script Editor, you need to authorise Script Editor too by adding it to the list described above)